# How to minimize whitespace around Baidu's echarts

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I'm trying to incorporate Baidu's echarts (which look really good). However, there is a lot of whitespace around the actual graph when one doesn't set a title nor uses their toolbar. Is there a way to have the graph/chart use more of the canvas?

My current solution to add an extra  inside the container one and then set it's width and height to be be bigger by the margins I want to remove and the offset it by setting 'top' and 'left' to negative values of the respective margins. Not elegant and more importantly, not robust, but it works for the moment.

Comment: you dont make your poit clear, which chart do you mean ? there is many example in thair website which is not mach with your question

Comment: My question applies to all charts. They all have the same structure. They have space for the title and toolbar and if you don't need them, the charts don't fill out that space. In my case I have my own title and toolbar outside the chart's div.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### In ECharts 4, 5

As mentioned by some other posters, the correct way to get rid of the whitespace is to change `options.grid`.

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid

```
grid: {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0
}
```

In ECharts 4, the names of the grid properties have been changed to `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`.

Thanks to the answers above for pointing me in the right direction!

Further, changing the `option.legend`, as suggested above, had no effect on my chart.

Comment: At least it was only 20 mins @YegorZaremba -- I remember struggling with this detail for quite a while!

Comment: The link is dead. New link, https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid

Answer (score 10):

In ECharts **3** you can use the options `grid.left`, `grid.top`, `grid.right` and/or `grid.bottom`. According to the documentation, left and right default to 10%, and top and bottom default to 60 (px).

Documentation: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid.

```js
const option = {
  // these are the grid default values
  grid: {
    top:    60,
    bottom: 60,
    left:   '10%',
    right:  '10%',
  },
  // your other options...
}
```

Comment: @David for pie charts you have to set `radius: '100%'`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the properties defined on the grid (x, y, x2 and y2). 
These properties are mentioned on the documentation: http://echarts.baidu.com/doc/doc-en.html#Grid

Comment: This answer applies to ECharts 2. For ECharts 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666132/1819283.

Answer (score 7):

Adding values to your themes grid object, like so:

```
var theme = {

    grid: {
        x: 40,
        y: 20,
        x2: 40,
        y2: 20
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've provided an updated answer for ECharts 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
legend: {
padding: 0,
itemGap: 0,
data: [' ', ' ']
    },
```

In here we can just simply remove the padding of the legend. even though you are not specifying one, it is taking the default values. Unfortunately, eCharts doesn't give flexible option of setting chartArea through options.
In google Charts you can mention it 100% and it'll cover all the available area. I tried the above mentioned work around and could cover a bit more space after that.

Answer (score -2):

in Echart u can make chart/graph with combination of the chart, and thre is too many config for every charts section, like legend, etc... just have look at their [api documantation](http://echarts.baidu.com/doc/doc-en.html) on their web site and [Example](http://echarts.baidu.com/doc/example-en.html) page (Combinations part)